# Audio Processing Software That Pitch Shifts Based On Original Pitch

Tags: audio

> X is input, Y is output.
>
> [image]
>
> - Far Left: WaveShaper
> - Left: Distortion
> - Right: Equalizer
> - Far Right: Hmmm...

I need an app that takes an input audio track, adjusts the output frequency based on its original frequency, and outputs a pitch-distorted track.

Comment: An app for Android? For iOS? A Web-App? What's your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Let me see if I'm understanding correctly. If your input is some recognizable, in-tune melody, you want the software to convert it so that the output is **not** merely the same melody in another key? So for example, one possible application of this software could be to simulate a person who can't carry a tune, as they attempt to sing a well-known song?

Comment: @JohnY Yes. &nbsp;

Comment: Why do you call the second graphics "Distortion"? Ain't that the curve of an amplifier?

Comment: @Thomas Weller It does not have to be a straight line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it's unclear what exactly is needed. Please update the graphics in your question to show what you actually need. I can't give an answer for a question with wrong requirements.

Answer (score 2):

[Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) has an effect which will change the pitch, *while maintaining tempo,* for you.

[image]

- Free, Open Source & Gratis
- Available for most platforms
- of course it does a lot more besides

Comment: That's not what I want. I need to shift the pitch based on the pitch.

Comment: @Duh-Wayne-101 Do you mean that you wish to shift the pitch by a __different__ amount according to the original pitch?

Comment: Yes, that is the functionality I want.